# Having PDO::fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS) return a null-valued instance of the object instead of a bool(false)

Tags: php, oop, pdo

My users manage the clients of the company via a web interface. They can navigate to clients using (amongst otherways) an input to directly choose a client id, which will show them the client entry.

To do that, I use PDO::FETCH_CLASS to map database values in php objects. Those objects are then used to generate html; said html will be displayed to the screen as the client id.

```
$oSTMT = $oDB->prepare("SELECT id,name FROM clients WHERE id=?");
$oSTMT->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,'client');
$oSTMT->execute(array(12673));
$oClient = $oSTMT->fetch(); // returns false when no row is selected
$oClient->makeHTML(); // which resultd in Fatal error: Call to a member function on a non-object
```

before redesigning to have an object wrap the fetched object so that it won't break if it is a boolean, I would try to have PDO generate an instanced object anyway.

My problem is twofold: entering a non-existent client id in the input and creating a new client. In both case the client id refers to no line in the database; `execute(array([values])` will return `bool(true)` (the statement executed sucessfully) but the `->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,'client')` will return a `bool(false)`

my solution is to create a client row with id=0 so that when it does not exists, I query with id=0 instead to get my "default" client row, but I was wondering:

**Is there a command to instruct `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` to generate an instance of selected object when no rows are selected by the statement?**

this would also prevent me from having to first verify if the id exists (which is not that costly, I'll admit, but I'd like not to have to)

Comment: You could manually create the class instance first, and then use the `FETCH_INTO` mode instead of `FETCH_CLASS`.

Comment: so that even if the result is false, the class would still exists with defaults as stated in the class. sounds good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instantiate the class first, and then use `FETCH_INTO` instead of `FETCH_CLASS`.

```
$client = new client();
$oSTMT = $oDB->prepare("SELECT id,name FROM clients WHERE id=?");
$oSTMT->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO,$client);
$oSTMT->execute(array(12673));
$client = $oSTMT->fetch();
$client->makeHTML();
```